# Postgresql: Trigger is not working at times

Tags: postgresql, trigger, insert, row, amazon-rds

I have a PostgreSQL trigger that is not firing sometimes, even though the status is always shown as "enabled".

My trigger code is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_src_exhibit() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' then
        if new.audit_created_date is null  THEN
        new.audit_created_date := current_timestamp;
        new.audit_created_by := session_user::text;
    end if;
    else
        if new.audit_modified_date is null  THEN
        new.audit_modified_date := current_timestamp;
        new.audit_modified_by := session_user::text;
    end if;
END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER audit_src_exhibit_tr
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON <table>
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_src_exhibit();
```

Is there any specific reason for this behaviour?
Does my code show any signs of known issues which would result in triggers not firing?

I find the audit columns populated as null when some insert happened today
[image]

Comment: Go here [SQL Formatter](https://sqlformat.darold.net/) and reformat the function to make it more readable and easier to follow the logic.

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of IF statement without else statement that can generate the situation you are telling.

Examples:

1. TG_OP is always INSERT? Or can be "Insert"? (case sensitive problem)
2. IF "new.audit_created_date is null".. else???
3. and again similar.

For debug, you can think about a table in which you write when TRIGGER do nothing.

ExAMPLES:

1. IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' then "doWork()" else "add in table "tg_op = value"".

I dont' think database not fire insert, I think you are skipping some IF branch.

Comment: Read the docs [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)  *TG_OP  Data type text; a string of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or TRUNCATE telling for which operation the trigger was fired.* This is not really an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue isn't that the trigger isn't firing.

Looking at the trigger code, you only check if `new.audit_created_date is null` if `TG_OP = 'INSERT'`.

That means you can perform an `UPDATE`, setting `audit_create_date` to `NULL`; the trigger would still fire, but the first branch of the `IF`, which sets `new.audit_create_date` to `current_timestamp`, would not execute as `TG_OP` is not equal to `INSERT`.

In that case, `new.audit_create_date` would still be `NULL` after trigger execution.